# Заносится пустая информация в БД

Tags: база-данных, php

В базу заносится пустая информация. Есть код, отправляющей информацию обработчику (метод пост), в обработчике эта информация заноситься в переменные. Если попробовать вывести переменный с echo, то ничего не выводит.

`if (isset($_POST['name'])){$name =$_POST['name'];
}` - заносим в переменную значение поля `name`. Почему информация заносится в БД как пустая?

Comment: Ну если echo пустоту выдаёт, то в посте пустое значение. Код приведите и вариант запроса к скрипту.

Comment: посмотрите в firebug как передается запрос может быть просто не передаются значения

Comment: isset не проверяет на пустое значение. Если передать name как пустое - то условие выполнится

Comment: http://tsya.ru/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `!empty()` вместо `isset()`.